# insert a variable into an url

Tags: python, csv, parsing, urllib2

I got a CSV file with numbers and I want to insert these numbers into a specific location in an url : jus after " "value": "
Here is my code :

```
with open('update_cases_id.csv') as p:
    for lines in p:
        uuid = lines.rstrip()

        url_POST = "www.example.com/"

        values = {}
        values['return_type'] = 'retrieval'
        values['format'] = 'TSV'
        values['size'] = '70'
        values['filters'] = '{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value": .format(uuid)}}]}'

        data = urllib.urlencode(values)

        url_final = url_POST + '?' + data

        req2 = urllib2.Request(url_final)
        req2.add_header('cookie', cookie)
        handle = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
```

( edited :
example input : 123456-123456-987654
example output : it s data text )

Comment: Please edit your question to include example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with string formatting, this should work for you:

```
# ...snip
values['filters'] = '{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value":%s}]}' % uuid
# snip...
```

The `%s` will be replaced by the uuid by the % replacement operator:

```
>>> values = {}
>>> uuid = 1234
>>> values['filters'] = '{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value":%s}]}' % uuid
>>> values
{'filters': '{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value":1234}]}'}
```

Comment: Made a mistake, this string formatting doesn't work due to the other braces in the string. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you 
This works :

values['filters'] = '{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value":["%s"]}}]}' % uuid

Comment: Ah, yes, to get is as a string (enclosed in "") you would need to call `str()` on `uuid` before the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Template`.

```
from string import Template
params = Template('{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value": ${your_value}}}]}')
params = params.safe_substitute(your_value=123)
# params is '{"op":"and","content":[{"op":"in","content":{"field":"cases.case_id","value":123}]}'
```